# Объединение Экспортных XML данных в MSSQL с исключение таблицы

Tags: xml, sql-server, объединение

Здравствуйте! Я новичек в MSSQL. 
Имеем 15 таблиц с общим количеством столбцов 500шт.
Подскажите как объединить результаты XML в один документ? UNION ALL не помогает.

У меня в БД добавилась Таблица с адресами MSSQL серверов и их ID.
Поэтому возникла необходимость исключить её из результатов.
Взял запрос:

```
Select(
SELECT 'TABLE1' as 'name' ,                --выводит в тэге XML имя таблицы   
(      SELECT *       FROM 'TABLE1'        --таблица 1
FOR XML RAW ('Columns') ,type        )     --формат выгрузки данных
FOR XML RAW, type                          --формат выгрузки данных


SELECT 'TABLE2' as 'name' ,      
(      SELECT *       FROM 'TABLE2'
FOR XML RAW ('Columns') ,type        )     

FOR XML RAW, type)
```

Но объеденить его с помощью UNION не получается.
Смысл в том, чтобы у меня были заголовки столбцов в выгрузке. 
И результаты писались в один файл.

**Помогите пожалуйста.**

*За 2-дня я так и не смог победить ... 
Буду признателен за любую помощь и примеры.*

До этого использовал:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
DECLARE @CMD varchar(max) = ''

DECLARE @AllTablesXML table (XMLData XML)
SELECT @CMD += 
  ';SELECT '''+TABLE_NAME+''' as ''@name'' ,
    (
    SELECT * 
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_NAME) +
    'FOR XML RAW (''Columns'') ,type ' + CHAR(10) + '
    )
   FOR XML RAW, type'
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
  --WHERE T.TABLE_NAME in  ('your List of tables') Uncomment if you need to extract specific tables

--SELECT @CMD

--Exec (@CMD)

INSERT INTO @AllTablesXML
EXEC (@CMD) 


SELECT XMLData 
FROM @AllTablesXML
FOR XML RAW
```

Comment: Приведите пример данных в таблицах и тот XML который хотите получить на выходе. Исправить вопрос можно по ссылке "правка" под вопросом. А предыдущий аналогичный вопрос удалите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил данный вопрос:

```
SELECT 'TABLE1' as 'name' ,      
(      SELECT *       FROM 'TABLE1'
FOR XML RAW ('Columns') ,type        )    ---  нужно добавить в () (скобки)


Итоговый результат кода:

(SELECT 'TABLE1' as 'name' ,      
(SELECT *       FROM 'TABLE1'
FOR XML RAW ('Columns') ,type))     
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TABLE2' as 'name' ,      
(SELECT *       FROM 'TABLE2'
FOR XML RAW ('Columns') ,type))    
FOR XML RAW, type
```

В итоге получаем:

```
<row name="TABLE1">
  <Columns ID="5" iSPCModuleNo="22" iMidx="100" " />
  <Columns ID="4" iSPCModuleNo="255" iMidx="4" />
</row>
<row name="TABLE2">
  <Columns ID="133" iBSIModuleNo="133" iLocalIPAddr1="10" />
  <Columns ID="134" iBSIModuleNo="134" iLocalIPAddr1="10" />
</row>
```

Повторюсь, что при селекте из вопроса, Студия дает 2-а файла с результатами, а нужен один.

Вот пример:
[image: Пример обычного вывода результата]